# Promise: Async flow in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

Hi I am new to asynchronous programming. I am unable to understand if a promise resolves successfully does the code still be asynchronous.
For example:
module A has function A() which returns a promise.
I require module A in module B and call function A()
The code in module B will look like:

```
Section X: some code in module B
Section Y: ModuleA.functionA().then((result) => {
           somevariableInModuleB = result; 
            // assign the result from A() to some variable in module B.
           // some more logic goes here....
        });
Section Z: some more code in module B....
```

So, does this code execute synchronously i.e., first section X then Y and then Z?
or do I have to modify it like:

```
Section X: some code in module B
Section Y: ModuleA.functionA().then((result) => {somevariableInModuleB = result;})
Section Z: .then(() => {some more code in module B....});
```

Does this ensure that?

Comment: The fact that some of this code is in another module is completely irrelevant; everything you want to do with `result` has to happen inside `.then()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the code inside the `then()` will be executed synchronously.

In your top example, Section Z maybe be executed before the code inside of the promise in section B.

In your bottom example, the `then()` is not attached to a promise and thus wouldn't work.

To make it synchronous, you want to change it to look like this:

```
Section X: some code in module B
Section Y: ModuleA.functionA().then((result) => {
  somevariableInModuleB = result;
  some more code in module B....
})
```

Anything you want to do with `result` has to happen inside `.then()`.

Comment: Thanks @Davia, in case I am done with all the logic with result inside section Y. Do I still need to bring code in section Z inside? What I understand is that if result or somevariableInModuleB have to be used everything comes inside the then() or the following then().